# Query to omit fields (NOT RECORD) if specified field is null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table `[tblAttributeData]` that has a single primary key field for "Product Number". Each product number may have anywhere from 1 to 37 attributes—each attribute consists of 3 fields: `Attribute Name`, `Attribute Value`, and `Attribute Unit-of-Measure`.

e.g. [Catalog Number] [Attribute 1] [Value 1] [UOM 1] [Attribute 2] [Value 2] [UOM 2] . . . etc.

There may be more attributes named then there are attributes given value/unit.

I also have a query that pulls the `Attribute Name` as well as a concatenated field for value + unit, resulting in 2 fields per attribute.

e.g. [Attribute 1] [concValue 1] [Attribute 2] [concValue 2] . . . etc.

So here's my problem: I have to populate a report of any attribute that has a value, which is easily done. However I need to populate a set of text boxes for each of these attributes, but I need to omit any record whose `[concValue]` is null and *not* skip a row in the set of text boxes.

I can't seem to use the criteria field, because if any one of the `[concValue]` returns null then the entire record is omitted, and not just that particular `[Attribute #]` and `[concValue #]`.

Is there a way to omit a couple fields in any given record without maintaining a value of `Null` in those fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only by redesigning your base table (`tblAttributeData`) and splitting it up into two tables: one for product data and one for attribute data. The product data table might be fairly simple, just a product ID and a name. Plus whatever else you need. The attributes table would then have to store attributes one per row, referring to the products table. I'll just specify the tables using SQL for brevity:

```
create table tblProducts (
  ID autoincrement primary key
, [Name] varchar(100)
, Description varchar(255)
);

create table tblAttributes (
  ID autoincrement primary key
, ProductID long not null references tblProducts (ID)
, [Name] varchar(100)
, UoM varchar(10)
, [Value] double
);
```

The rationale for this design is that you are currently storing up to 37 copies of essentially the same data along your table columns. This is a perfect candidate for restructuring from horizontal to vertical. Under this new design you would naturally show all products and leave out all attributes whose values are `null` because by design they would *simply not be present in the `tblAttributes` table.* To do this you would just need to do a normal inner join:

```
select *
from tblProducts as p
inner join tblAttributes as a
on p.ID = a.ProductID
```